# How to drop packet if conntrack entry not present

Tags: iptables, routing, ip-conntrack

Is there a way to check if conntrack exists before doing a particular action in iptable chains ?

I would like to drop the packet in mangle-postrouting if conntrack entry is not present, dont want it to go to nat-postrouting. By Postrouting I expect conntrack to be created, if its not there then it means,pakcet is invalid & should be dropped.

How do I do that, any suggestions ?

Comment: This is for a packet that initiated a session (such as a TCP SYN) or a packet that is part of an already established session? If the latter, then what you want is trivial: `iptables -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j  action`.

Comment: Yes , I also thought the same initially. But for a traffic we are sending only echo replies (through traffic generator), in this case it somehow meets the ESTABLISHED rule but conntrack is not created for this connection.